extracting data from an array within a bounding box defined by latitude and longitude
I have 'rh_irr’ which is an array of size 744*171*162 where 171 is latitude, 162 is longitude and 744 is time dimension. I also have arrays lat and lon both have size of 171*162 and contains corresponding latitude and longitudes of the data. I need to extract data within the bounding box -115.3 to -115.5 longitude, and 32.5 to 33.1 latitude.
import numpy as np

# Define the latitude and longitude ranges
lat_min, lat_max = 32.5, 33.1
lon_min, lon_max = -115.5, -115.3

# Find the indices of latitudes and longitudes within the specified range
lat_indices = np.where((lat >= lat_min) & (lat <= lat_max))[0]
lon_indices = np.where((lon >= lon_min) & (lon <= lon_max))[1]

# Extract the data within the specified range
extracted_data = rh_irr[:, lat_indices, :][:, :, lon_indices]

# Print the shape of the extracted data
print("Shape of extracted data:", extracted_data.shape)


The above code executes and hopefully it will do what I want to do but is crashing. How can we make it more memory efficient? Please suggest if there is another better way.

but is crashing - what error are you facing?

I am running in google colab and it is crashing because it is using more than allowed 12gb memory.

What type objects are you filling your array with?  Primitive values should not causes this much memory usage.

The data, lat, lon all are float type.

The np.where() function uses additional memory for storing indices where a condition is True but it shouldn't impact on the memory usage significantly. If you apply boolean masks directly to the rh_irr array to extract the subset, it will avoid unnecessary memory allocations. You can use the memory-profiler module to monitor the memory consumption.
import numpy as np

# Define the latitude and longitude ranges
lat_min, lat_max = 32.5, 33.1
lon_min, lon_max = -115.5, -115.3

# Create boolean masks for latitude and longitude
lat_mask = (lat >= min_lat) & (lat <= max_lat)
lon_mask = (lon >= min_lon) & (lon <= max_lon)

# Apply boolean masks directly on the array
selected_data = rh_irr[:, lat_mask, :][:, :, lon_mask]

# Check the shape of selected_data
print("Shape of selected_data:", selected_data.shape)


I tried your suggestion but it gave the following error. I would like to mention that the lat and lon values do not have uniform intervals across the grids. However, the array sizes of lat (171162) and lon (171162) are consistent with the lat and lon dimension of the data (744171162).
---> 12 selected_data = rh_irr[:, lat_mask, :][:, :, lon_mask]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 4 were indexed.
